# How can I convert DWORD or string to BYTE*

Tags: c++, file, winapi

Hello I am creating a file encryption code I read a file and I need to turn the file that I am reading to BYTE* I tried searching but every single time I got `"CL.exit"`. This is how I read the file.

```
HANDLE getFile = createFile();
    DWORD reciveBytes = 0;
    //If it's byte or kilobyte the size of the buffer will be 1024.
    //If it's megabytes or gigabyte the size of the buffer will be 4096.
    const DWORD Buffersize = 66232; // gave me warning for 1024
    DWORD buffer[Buffersize];
    string fileInput;
    if (ReadFile(
        getFile,
        buffer,
        Buffersize,
        &reciveBytes,
        NULL
    )) {
    }
    else {
        cout << "Faild!" << endl;
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    /*
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < reciveBytes; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] != '\0') {
            fileInput = fileInput + buffer[i];
        }
    }
    */
    return buffer[reciveBytes];
```

now, what I need to do is to turn the return type to BYTE* so I could do something like this:  `BYTE* protect = (BYTE*)"Hello world!";`
This is createFile():

```
HANDLE getFile = CreateFileA(
        fileName,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
        NULL
    );
```

Comment: You cannot return a pointer to a local variable. Once your function returns, `buffer` is gone for good. You should probably have something `BYTE *buffer = malloc(Buffersize);` in the first place and then `return buffer;`. But anyway the question remains pretty unclear, especially the `BYTE* protect = (BYTE*)"Hello world!";` part

Comment: @Jabberwocky It was just an example of me trying to show you want I want to do. like how the parameter should work like. so the parameter should be like the Hello world. So what I need to do is to do the "*buffer = malloc(Buffersize);" inside the readingfile and then return buffer?

Comment: It's still unclear. If you are unable to explain it in english, then show some examples.

Comment: Also, your error handling is wrong. You need to call `GetLastError` immediately after the API call returns. In your code you stream to `cout` which could call another API function and so modify the error code.

Comment: As for reading a file. Allocate a buffer and read into it with `ReadFile`. Or better, use C++ standard library stream classes to read the file. Why do you want to use Win32 API which is complex when the standard library makes it simple? You ask how to convert DWORD or string into a byte array, but the code you show is about reading a file. Which has no DWORD or string. Your code already attempts to read directly into a byte array. And we can only see a very small part of the code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky there is no code example to it. If i do something like BYTE* protect = (BYTE*)"Hello world!" it would work

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah you are right I forgot to put it after because it worked if I returned a string

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want to use winapi there I want to do it with winapi and not fstream or something like that. in addition it doesn't have to be DWORD or string if it could be something else it's fine to but I'll need to change the code more I guess

Comment: What is the content like of the file you want to read?

Comment: You can certainly declare an array of bytes.

Comment: If you want to read `BYTE*`, why not define `buffer` as `BYTE` array type directly? `BYTE buffer [Buffersize*sizeof (DWORD)];` "`return buffer [reciveBytes]`", it seems that you want to return the array, but it's wrong to write that way. You need to first apply for a memory(let's say `BYTE* memory`) that will not be automatically released at the end of a function, copy from buffer(or pass `memory` directly into `ReadFile`), and then `return memory;`.

Comment: @DrakewuMSFT thank you I'll try it

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT but where do i put memory in  fileinput like how is it connected where can i pass it in readFile

Comment: `ReadFile(getFile,memory,Buffersize,&reciveBytes,NULL);`

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT and now just return memory?

Comment: Yes, But don't forget to request memory for `memory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
HANDLE createFile()
{
    HANDLE getFile = CreateFileA(
        "xxx.txt",
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
        return getFile;
}
BYTE* memoryfromfile()
{
    HANDLE getFile = createFile();
    DWORD reciveBytes = 0;
    //If it's byte or kilobyte the size of the buffer will be 1024.
    //If it's megabytes or gigabyte the size of the buffer will be 4096.
    const DWORD Buffersize = 66232; // gave me warning for 1024
    BYTE* memory = new BYTE[Buffersize];
    memset(memory, 0, Buffersize);
    std::string fileInput;
    if (ReadFile(
        getFile,
        memory,
        Buffersize,
        &reciveBytes,
        NULL
    )) {
    }
    else {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Faild!" << std::endl;
    }
    /*
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < reciveBytes; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] != '\0') {
            fileInput = fileInput + buffer[i];
        }
    }
    */
    return memory;
}
int main()
{
    BYTE * temp = memoryfromfile();
    std::cout << "temp = " << temp << std::endl;
    delete temp;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's weird. I got "CL.exe"

Comment: Could you please share your reproducible sample?Or use my sample code that updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199723/discussion-between-drake-wu-msft-and-r4z7).